# Application-Defined or Object-Defined error on a conditional function when doing a loop

Tags: vba, loops, error-handling

I've written the following code to copy into cells of certain range of worksheet(1) values of a certain range of worksheet(2) that doesn't match within a certain range of worksheet(3):

```
  Sub sortdata()

Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim w2 As Worksheet
Dim w1 As Worksheet
Dim w3 As Worksheet
Dim SW As String
Dim qrycolvaly As Range
Dim qrycolvalt As Range
Dim r As Range
Dim canceled(1 To 5) As String
Dim performed(1 To 200) As String
Dim startcell As Range


    Set w2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
    Set w1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set w3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3)
    Set startcell = w1.Range("B9")
    Set r = w3.Range("C1").End(xlDown)
    Set qrycolvaly = w3.Range("C1", r)

    For i = 1 To 200
        With w2
            SW = .Cells(i + 1, 3).Value
            If IsError(WorksheetFunction.Match(SW, qrycolvaly, 0)) = True Then
                performed(i) = SW
            End If
        End With
        startcell.Offset(i - 1, 0).Value = performed(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

When there is a `SW` (certain value of sepcified range of worksheet 2) that doesn't match with values of the specified range of worksheet 3, my code stops on the instruction:

```
 If IsError(WorksheetFunction.Match(SW, qrycolvaly, 0)) = True Then
```

With the error:

> 1004:Application-Defined or Object-Defined error

I've tried so many things, specially change type of variables when dim them, but I don't get to make it work.

¿Could anyone tell me what am I doing Wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Application.Match` in place of `WorksheetFunction.Match`, it is the VBA equivalent function and won't generate the error message.

You are then using two VBA functions (with `IsError`) rather than a VBA and an Excel function.

`WorksheetFunction.Match` returns the Excel value `#N/A`, whereas `Application.Match` returns a VBA error value which `IsError` recognises (Error 2042).